# Parsing XML with Namespace causing fatal error

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, namespaces

I am having trouble using registerXPathNamespace to display properly values from the xml file. Can someone please point what I am doing wrong?  I am new to XML with namespaces.

Here is the code I am using

```
$cpe = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

$sxe=new SimpleXMLElement($cpe);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('ipdr','http://www.ipdr.org/namespaces/ipdr');

$result0=$sxe->xpath('ipdr:IPDR->BulkData[0]')->Value;
$result1=$sxe->xpath('ipdr:IPDR->BulkData[1]')->Value;

echo $result0 ' <br> ' $result1;
```

Here is the XML file test.xml

```
<ipdr:IPDRDoc xmlns:ipdr="http://www.ipdr.org/namespaces/ipdr"
xmlns="urn:broadband-forum-org:ipdr:tr-232-1-0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:broadband-forum-org:ipdr:tr-232-1-0 tr-232-1-0-0-serviceSpec.xsd http://www.ipdr.org/namespaces/ipdr http://www.ipdr.org/public/IPDRDoc3.5.1.xsd"
docId="74697373-6f74-7878-7878-746973736f74"
creationTime="2013-06-11T05:52:55.153Z"
IPDRRecorderInfo="TEST IPDR Collector"
version="3.5.1">
    <ipdr:IPDR xsi:type="BulkDataReport">
    <BulkData>
        <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.UpTime</Name>
        <Value>1449</Value>
    </BulkData>
    <BulkData>
        <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.ManagementServer.URL</Name>
        <Value>www.yahoo.com</Value>
    </BulkData>
    </ipdr:IPDR >
    <ipdr:IPDRDoc.End count="1" endTime="2013-06-11T05:52:55.207Z"></ipdr:IPDRDoc.End>
</ipdr:IPDRDoc>
```

Comment: I looked at the related questions and found many answers for the situation where the child elements have name space.  In my case, even the root element has namespace assigned. This is confusing me.

Comment: Which language is this? PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it to work.  Here is the code I used to get URL value from my text.xml file.

```
$url = $xml->xpath("//ns:BulkData[ns:Name='InternetGatewayDevice.ManagementServer.URL']/ns:Value"); 
$url = $url[0];
```